# Check for existance of loaded JavaScript libraries for my app's use otherwise load my own versions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a Project Management application as a SugarCRM Plugin.

In my app, which uses a lot of JavaScript, exscecially for a part that shows a Project Task record in a popup Modal Div.

So on the page there is HTML for 1 Modal Div.  I then update the Task record fields inside of that 1 modal every time a new task record is clicked on.  It brings the Task Modal into view and updates all the task fields and re-initiates all the JavaScript code that works on those fields.

For example almost all the data fields for a Task record that are shown in the modal div have Edit-in-place capability using the jQuery library called X-Editable.  There is also a scrollbar plugin for custom scrolling inside of the Modal, Datepicker library, and some more little plugins here and there.  As well as all my custom code, hundreds o lines for this section alone!

Now that I explained the app a little bit, I can move on to the questions...

**SugarCRM v6.x.x** uses **jQueryUI DatePicker plugin** for it's own Date Selectors.

**SugarCRM v7.x.x** changes and uses **Bootstrap DatePicker library** (this one http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/)

So in my plugin app I have considered both of these for my Date field needs since they are already loaded into the page anyways!

Once issue I have is the SugarCRM v6 vs v7 using different libraries.

But that isn't a real big issues as I am able to build 2 versions and target the code to the correct version for the user.

My question is, knowing that these libraries get loaded into the page, is there a reliable way for my app to check for there existence and use them if they exist?  And then if they do not, load my own versions?

Or am I better off loading my own version, even though it could be loaded into the page already?

Comment: I don't know those specific libraries, but you can usually just do a feature test to check for the existence of some API that the library implements.  if it is present, then the library is present.  If the API is not present, then the library is not loaded.

Comment: To piggy back on jfriend00's statement.  You could implement a Modernizer type tactic, on your initial page (like index.html), where you say:  if(!SomeLibrary) {//load my library}

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks, I think I understand the concept.  My lack of JS experience I am not sure exactly how to implement such a test but this is a good start!

Comment: @JasonWilczak Thanks as well, I mentioned i'm not sure really how to do such a check yet but the overall concept I like!  Perhaps looking at Modernizr itself can be of assistance for me as well to see how they do such functionality.  I know how to load in JS files (in fact just read an article yesterday about it from the guy who made the functionality on StackExchange sites for loading in scripts as needed, i'll link it here for reference,) I just need to figure out a good "test" for both these libraries

Comment: @JasonWilczak Article I mentioned for loading in remote scripts on StackOverflow http://balpha.de/2011/10/jquery-script-insertion-and-its-consequences-for-debugging/ it's a bit old now but I think still relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use duck typing to check what script is loaded. For the bootstrap version, you can check if the `$.fn.datepicker.Constructor` method exists; it's exclusive to that script. The jqueryui version has the same property but in lowercase.

Edit cause I didn't notice the last part of the question. If none of the scripts have loaded, you can load your own the same way the HTML5 Boilerplate does (assuming we are still working on the datepicker):

```
<script>window.MyLibrary || document.write('<script src="//routeToMyScript.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

```
<script>$().datepicker || document.write('<script src="//routeToMyScript.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

Comment: `window.MyLibrary || document.write('<script src="//routeToMyScript.js"><\/script>')` So this code checks if `window.MyLibrary` exists and if it does not then it loads the script to the right is that correct?  As for checking if this is loaded `$.fn.datepicker.Constructor.prototype.fillDow` could you show a demo of how to check for that please?  I'm still learning a lot of JS so plenty that I'm not certain of how to do yet, thanks for the help and ideas

Comment: I see your comment about the last part now, it's perfect!  Just uncertain of the first part

Comment: The first part, yes. If the library does not exist, you `document.write` (i.e. write) a `script` element that loads a local version of the script.

For the second part, it has to be improved. Usually you just can do `if ($.fn.datepicker.Constructor.prototype.fillDow) { }` but with the jqueryui version it can fail if `datepicker` or `Constructor` properties do not exist.

Comment: @JasonDavis I updated my answer so your script won't explode if you have one library but not the other. Check first paragraph. Also changed how you can load your local version of the script.